# CSS - why does my JS script take the full height?

Tags: javascript, css

I try to make the Gallery.js script appear above the header. I can only make it display next to it, because by default the script takes the whole height. How can I change it?

```
<div className="App">
    <Gallery images={this.state.IMAGES} />
    <header className="App-header">
        <Link to="/success">
            <button variant="outlined">
                back
            </button>
        </Link>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide more code and also your style

Comment: @k-wasilewski what are you trying to say please explain little more and provide your requirement screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.App-header {
   min-height: 100vh;
}
```

.App-header has as min height the full heigth